# Query to search substring in column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has a substring value in the column and I want to write a query that checks if input string has the substring.

My table looks like:

```
| company | host       |
| ------- | ---------- |
| ebay    | ebay.com   |
| google  | google.com |
| yahoo   | yahoo.com  |
```

My input will be like www.ebay.com or https://www.ebay.com or www.qa.ebay.com or www.dev.ebay.com..

If I get any of the inputs I want to return the first record.

I tried looking at the CHARINDEX, INSTR but they are work in reverse. My scenario is I have substring to be searched in table and the actual string as input.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Did you search MySQL docs for substring perhaps?

Comment: It would be helpful to state clearly something like: if my input is X, I want the output to be Y.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `like` for this, but you also need string concatenation.  In ANSI standard SQL, this looks like:

```
select t.*
from t
where @inputstring like concat('%.', t.host)
```

where `@inputstring` is the string you are inputting.

Note:  You can also use the concatenation infix operation, which is typically `||` (standard) or `+`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SQL wildcard like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE host LIKE '%ebay.com';
```

Answer (score 1):

Go for this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE host LIKE '%SearchString%'
```

It will pull all rows containing the SearchString.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using like operator.

Select * from yourtable
where ? like concat('%', company, '%');

parameter ? with your input.